# Ruby/Nokogiri nested loop in Nexpose XML results parser failing

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I am trying to write a ruby script to take the Nexpose Simple XML results export, parse it, and write the required results out to a prettier format for easy review. I am using Nokogiri to parse the XML. My issue is that I have a nested loop that for each device, iterates through each service section and pulls out the name, port, and protocol attributes from each one. This will ultimately be printed back out to a file either a text file or a csv. However, my nested loops seems to only pull those three attributes from the first service section and prints them repeatedly.

**Sample Input (there will be more than one of these device blocks):**

```
<device address="10.x.x.1" id="20xx">
<fingerprint certainty="0.85">
<description>Microsoft Windows</description>
<vendor>Microsoft</vendor>
<family>Windows</family>
<product>Windows</product>
<version/>
<device-class>General</device-class>
<architecture/>
</fingerprint>
<vulnerabilities>
</vulnerabilities>
<services>
<service name="NTP" port="123" protocol="udp">
<vulnerabilities>
</vulnerabilities>
</service>
<service name="HTTP" port="8080" protocol="tcp">
<fingerprint certainty="0.75">
<description>Apache</description>
</device>

<device address="10.x.x.2" id="20xx">
<fingerprint certainty="0.85">
<description>Microsoft Windows</description>
<vendor>Microsoft</vendor>
<family>Windows</family>
<product>Windows</product>
<version/>
<device-class>General</device-class>
<architecture/>
</fingerprint>
<vulnerabilities>
</vulnerabilities>
<services>
<service name="DNS" port="53" protocol="udp">
<vulnerabilities>
</vulnerabilities>
</service>
<service name="HTTP" port="80" protocol="tcp">
<fingerprint certainty="0.75">
<description>Apache</description>
</device>
```

**Ruby Code:**

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(open('report.xml').read)
device = doc.xpath('//device')

device.each do |d|
 service = d.xpath('//service')
 puts d.attr('address')

 service.each do |s|
   name = s.attr('name')
   port = s.attr('port')
   protocol = s.attr('protocol')

   puts port
   puts protocol
   puts name
 end
end
```

**Desired Output:**

```
10.x.x.1
123
udp
NTP
8080
tcp
HTTP

10.x.x.2
53
udp
DNS
80
tcp
HTTP
```

**Actual Output:**

```
123
NTP
udp
123
NTP
udp
```

So the code should show a list of service port, name, and protocol for each service of each device. However, the current code seems to just print the set for the first service (which is 123, NTP, and udp) over and over and over.

Am I missing something in the logic of my loop? Or do you see anything wrong with the loops? Any help getting this working would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the XPath construct `//` means find the element *anywhere* in the document. You don't want to do that in the inner loop, because you've already done that for your device.

**Update**

Based on the new input document, here is one way to extract the information you need. I took the liberty of using CSV, for a nice Excel-ready output file. Note that there is a *single* parsing loop. Code:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'csv'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(open('report.xml').read)

CSV.open("devices.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  csv << ["Device", "Service", "Port", "Protocol"]
  doc.search('//service').each do |s|
    device = s.xpath('ancestor::device[1]/@address')
    name = s.attr('name')
    port = s.attr('port')
    protocol = s.attr('protocol')
    csv << [device, name, port, protocol]
  end
end
```

Here's the contents of `devices.csv`:

```
Device,Service,Port,Protocol
10.x.x.1,NTP,123,udp
10.x.x.1,HTTP,8080,tcp
10.x.x.2,DNS,53,udp
10.x.x.2,HTTP,80,tcp
```

Comment: I made your suggested changes and added a line in the device loop to put the device address. So the output should currently be an IP address and then the ugly list of all its ports, then the next IP and so forth. Well, it is at least pulling in the info for the additional services. However it looks like it is printing the first IP address, then all the services for all of the devices, then the second IP address, and then all the services for all of the devices, rinse and repeat. Shouldn't service loop be constrained to a single device section as they're iterated through in the device loop?

Comment: In your sample code, you don't seem to be using device for anything. You can remove it. I've updated my answer.

Comment: It should be used to iterate through multiple device sections in an input xml file. So picture the sample input provided above repeated multiple times for multiple different hosts. So my loops (at least I hope) should be iterating through each device section and pulling all the services for that section, then moving on to the next device. Instead, I'm currently getting output of device A's address, then every device's list of services, device B's address, then every device's list of services, all the way down the list.

Comment: I've updated my Ruby Code section to reflect what the current code is.

Comment: You're making the same mistake. You are asking for ALL services with `//service` and with your update it is now an inner loop. Like I said, you don't want `//` in an inner loop, because for EACH device in the outer loop you are asking for ALL services in the inner loop. In other words, you should have only ONE `//` in total. Fix that and it will work, but not be optimal. My second point is that you don't need to iterate. You need service information, so you can just find all services, no matter that they are in multiple devices.

Comment: Then I must be really confused. How can they not be nested loops? I tried the code snippet you provided and it appears to only print one long list of every device's service info. I am trying to get that list broken up and grouped by each device. I have updated the "Desired Output" section above to clarify. And also clarified on the sample input that there will be more than one of those device blocks. As for the //service, shouldn't that query for all services be limited to only those within that device section that the outer loop is currently on? Thanks for helping me out with this btw.

Comment: Your "Desired Output" doesn't reflect the requirements in your comments. Nevertheless, you don't need to stop and iterate. I have a blog post about this, but the blog is currently down. However, if you update your Sample Input and Desired Output to be *really* what you want, then I can show you how you don't need to iterate.

Comment: I updated desired output and sample input. Does that clarify what I'm looking for? I'll eventually end up cleaning up the format of the output, but I can handle that once I have the correct info being grabbed.

Comment: I updated my answer based on your new XML snippet. Note that it wasn't valid, as it was missing some closing tags, etc. Nevertheless, Nokogiri was able to handle it.

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm. I should be able to work off of that.